# Options for practice service worker

Tags: ssl, offline, offline-caching, service-worker, offlineapps

I would like to start learning how to create and use service workers in order to create an offline app. Is there a way that I can create and test a service worker local or online? With either a free SSL service or using HTTP? Or will I have to purchase an SSL certificate for my website?

As a side note I have already looked into encrypt it and my hosting platform (go daddy) doesn't support it without paying extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all browsers that support Service Workers (Firefox and Chrome) there should be a way to enable service workers for debugging purposes for any website.

In Firefox, from the developer tools options, you can enable "Enable Service Workers over HTTP (when toolbox is open)". See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Dev_tools.

They're always available from `localhost`, so you don't have to enable any option if you want to develop locally.